# MSO Conditional statments not working for background color

Tags: html, outlook, gmail, html-email, vector-graphics

Currently I'm creating an email template for a company.

The header that they are using isn't working in Microsoft Outlook. The background color isn't appearing. What should I do for this situation?

So far I've tried many of the conditional statements for MSO and still nothing has solved it.

Here is my code:

```
<table width="100%" class="header-bg">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="two-columns">

                            <table class="column">
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="padding: 35px 0px 50px 40px;">
                                        <a href="#"><img width="116px" src="https://i.imgur.com/qBESyOs.png"
                                                alt="CoStar"></a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="padding: 0px 0px 30px 40px;">
                                        <h2 style="font-size: 24px;margin:0;">A global leader in commercial real
                                            estate
                                            information, analytics, and news.</h2>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="padding: 14px 0px 50px 40px;">
                                        <div><!--[if mso]>
                                            <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="https://www.costar.com/" style="height:42px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:160px;" strokecolor="#1e3650" fillcolor="#0054A6">
                                              <w:anchorlock/>
                                              <center style="color:#ffffff;font-family: 'CoStar Brown';font-size:15px;font-weight:bold;">REQUEST DEMO</center>
                                            </v:rect>
                                          <![endif]--><a href="https://www.costar.com/"
                                                style="background-color:#0054A6;border:1px solid #1e3650;color:#ffffff;display:inline-block;font-family: 'CoStar Brown';font-size:15px;font-weight:bold;line-height:42px;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;width:160px;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;mso-hide:all;">REQUEST
                                                DEMO</a></div>

                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>

                            <table class="column">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>

                        </td>
                    </tr>

                </table>
```

So As you will see I'm trying to add a background to the class "header-bg".

I've also added inline styles and that hasn't worked either and also I tried this as well:

```
<!--[if mso]><table style="background-color:#000000;" width="100%"> 
                        <![endif]--><table width="100%" class="header-bg">
```

And nothing happened except for it removed the table opening tag.

Would love to hear what y'all would do and much appreciation for reading my post!